# SO Blog icon has partial white background when tab is inactive

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog, logo

When you open a tab on the [StackOverflow (company) blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com), and switch to another tab, the icon has a partial white background:

Firefox (Most obvious) - note the difference between that and the normal Stack Overflow logo

[image: Firefox]

IE

[image: Internet Explorer]

Edge

[image: Microsoft Edge]

Tested on Windows 10 with Firefox 41.0.2, Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge v20.10240.16384.0.

*(If someone could test this on chrome that would be great)*

Comment: Yes, [it looks ugly on Chrome too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268800/favicon-on-blog-stackoverflow-com-needs-to-be-updated-again).

Comment: Ps. While waiting for SE to fix this, I've added a client-side fix for this issue into the development branch of my [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script.

Comment: Looks like someone has put in a [pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/pull/194) to address this issue.

Comment: @D.G. Dammit, I knew I forgot something ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since quite recently](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/pull/194), the blog sports the shiny Stack Overflow favicon :)

[image]