# Blog favicon is not transparent

Tags: feature-request, bug, blog, favicon

Just noticed a difference between the blog favicon and Stack Overflow favicon:

> [image]

The ordinary favicon is transparent, while the blog favicon is not, which look worse.

Something similar was reported and "fixed" in [SO Blog icon has partial white background when tab is inactive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268784/so-blog-icon-has-partial-white-background-when-tab-is-inactive), but whatever was fixed has been changed again.

Can the blog favicon please get some well deserved transparency too?

Since the blog also hosts company related articles posting this here on MSE and not on MSO.

Comment: I've noticed that too, but I like it. The blog is so completely different from the rest of the site, it hardly seems right for it to have the same icon.

Comment: [Related post in MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322209/2451726)

Comment: @zondo it doesn't look professional, I'm sure the design team can think of better ways to distinguish the icons.

Comment: @Arulkumar thanks, I did search MSO before posting, but only for blog related stuff, that one is about the business page. Probably same source though.